# ASM how to check if method is overrided from a specific class

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

So I have a class called "SimpleVersion" overrides java Comparable
But I'm having trouble to check in ASM.

I have ClassNode instance for both classes and loop through their method, check if their name and desc is equals.
Here is the result of (name + " " + desc)

```
compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
compareTo (Lorg/imanity/imanityspigot/CompatibilityPatches$SimpleVersion;)I
```

As you can see here, the ClassNode I have for Comparable recognize their generic as Object, so desc check always fails.
Is there any way I can made it recognize the second method is override to the first method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When all but one method have the [`ACC_BRIDGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6-200-A.1) modifier set, the one without is the actual implementation method. But it’s possible that a class has multiple unrelated methods of the same name *and* some bridge methods. In that case, you’d have to do a far more elaborated analysis. But what are you trying to do exactly? For a lot of cases, there is no need to identify the actual method.

Comment: I'm trying to rename methods using asm, some may be renamed, some may not, so if a method is renamed but correspond method is not renamed then it will break codes.
So I want to avoid it by checking if the target method has any correspond method that shouldn't be renamed

Comment: The corresponding method of (the erased) `Comparable` still is `compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;)I`; that will never change. From the generic type system’s perspective, `compareTo (L…SimpleVersion;)I` is the implementation method of `Comparable<…SimpleVersion>` but that doesn’t matter to the callers using the `Comparable` interface. The bridge method consists of an invocation of the actual implementation method. So as long as you always care to adapt caller and callee on the bytecode level, the code will continue to work, even if you give those methods different names.